# Use array, loop, and conditional statement in SAS to get check cumulative sum at a specified starting position in data

Tags: arrays, loops, sas, survival-analysis, cumulative-sum

I'm doing a survival analysis and wanted to know if there's a better way to write the procedure below with an array and a loop.

I want to be able to specific a number of weeks in that last bit of code without having to write it all out. I'm trying to get the cumulative sum starting from variable *week* position (*week* is the fail week) going back *n* number of weeks. The variables w1-w52 are the status of a piece of equipment so I'm looking to see if a piece of equipment has been running for consecutive weeks prior to fail.

```
proc phreg data=dataset;
    model week*failure(1) = var1 var2 var3 var4 week week_runtime/ ties = efron;
    array weeks(*) w1-w52;

    /* This is the status of equipment at the week of fail */
    equipment_sts = weeks[week]; 
    
    /* This is where I'm trying to make my code more efficient so I can specify n weeks */
    if sum(weeks[week] + weeks[week-1] + weeks[week-2] + weeks[week-3] .... weeks[week - n]) = n then week_runtime = 1;
    else week_runtime = 0;
run;
```

Comment: Why are you trying to derive this new variable in the PHREG proc instead of just deriving the value in a data step and then using the variable in the proc step?

Comment: Less code needed in the procedure step.

Comment: Can you show some example input data and what value for WEEK_RUNTIME you want calculated for the example values.

Comment: Where did N come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what is the logic you are trying to create.  Sounds like you want a boolean flag, WEEK_RUNTIME, that is true when failure has not happened by WEEK.

I don't know if programming inside of PROC PHREG supports the full features of the DATA step but in a data step you could just use an iterative DO loop with a WHILE() clause to stop once you have found a failure.

```
data have ;
  input week week1-week5 ;
cards;
2 1 1 1 0 0
3 1 1 0 0 0
4 1 1 1 1 1
;

data want;
  set have;
  array weeks week1-week5 ;
  week_runtime=1;
  do index=1 to min(week,dim(weeks)) while (week_runtime=1);
    week_runtime=weeks[index];
  end;
  drop index;
run;
```

Results:

```
                                                             week_
Obs    week    week1    week2    week3    week4    week5    runtime

 1       2       1        1        1        0        0         1
 2       3       1        1        0        0        0         0
 3       4       1        1        1        1        1         1
```

**PS** If you do put this code into PROC PHREG watch out as I don't think that the original simpler ARRAY syntax is supported in procedures. You will have to add the superfluous `[*]` token between the name of the array and the list of variables.